# Create SSRS report to run on multiple records in dynamics crm

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, subreports

I want to get the activities against multiple records using SSRS. I made google a lot but didn't find sufficient information.

So, I want your kind suggestions about how can I create a report that will run on multiple records and display the report in any form like chart and tabular.

Comment: try with the Report Wizard, after back here to edit your question with the issues you have

Answer (score 0):

Do you asking about multiple parameters ?